# Sample image with CMYK channels and HSI channels?

Tags: opencv

I am learning OpenCV and would like to find any sample images which has CMYK channels and HSI channels. Thanks for providing.

Answer (score -1):

http://www.rgb2cmyk.org helps you convert any RGB color space images to CMYK color space. It is very difficult to get CMYK images directly becuase JPEG does not support CMYK space, but JPEG2000 supports it, which market has not moved into yet.

Another way of doing it is to read a RGB image and convert to HSI. The transformation from RGB to HSI is called CV_RGB2HLS in OpenCV.